# xpages view panel column multivalue separator

Tags: xpages

There is a column from a view which have the multi-value separator the new line.

[image]

But when I drag and drop this view inside my XPage ( as a  `<xp:viewpanel>` ) the multiple values are display within `,` and not in different lines.

I couldn't find any property in the view column. How can I achive this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try adding a converter of xp:convertList?  This is added in the All Properties under data for the view column.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to use customConverter here. Because convertList takes only one character as the seperator.

```
<xp:viewColumn
    columnName="SomeColumn"
    id="viewColumn1"
    contentType="html">
    <xp:this.converter>
        <xp:customConverter getAsObject="#{javascript:return value;}">
            <xp:this.getAsString>
                <![CDATA[#{javascript:return @Implode(value, "<br/>")}]]>
            </xp:this.getAsString>
        </xp:customConverter>
    </xp:this.converter>
    <xp:viewColumnHeader
        value="Header"
        id="viewColumnHeader1">
    </xp:viewColumnHeader>
</xp:viewColumn>
```

We are imploding values by `<br/>` string and providing content type so it won't escape the html output.

Comment: I tried to add this customConverter to another column but it isn;t working . Am I missing something: <xp:viewColumn columnName="$2" id="viewColumn5"
   contentType="html">
   <xp:this.converter>
    <xp:customConverter getAsObject="#{javascript:return value;}">
     <xp:this.getAsString>
                <![CDATA[#{javascript:return @Implode(value, "<br/>")}]]>
     </xp:this.getAsString>
    </xp:customConverter>
   </xp:this.converter>
  
   <xp:viewColumnHeader value="Telefon" id="viewColumnHeader5">
   </xp:viewColumnHeader>
  </xp:viewColumn>

Comment: The column displays the values in single line, separated by space.

Comment: Make sure the column value is multivalue. Remove the converter, it should be commo seperated.

Comment: i removed the converter and still the values are separated by space, in a single line. Column value is multivalue - how can I check it? Are you reffering to the clasical lotus Notes view or the view panel column ?